# white bar now appearing below my animated gradient background

Tags: css, background-image

After adding a second row of fancybox galleries there is now a white bar stretching along the bottom of the screen in all browsers (desktop and mobile). What could have caused it? My background is set at height: 100% and was working perfectly until this!! Would love some help! http://studiopowell.net/TEST_gradient.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body{
     background-color: #FFF;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;

 }

 #contain{
     display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
   position: relative;
     -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
 }

 #wrapper{
     display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
   position: relative;

     }

  #wrapper2{
     display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
   position: relative;

     }

 .titles {
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#33;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
     display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* works with row or column */
   flex-direction: column;
   -webkit-align-items: center;
   align-items: center;
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;


}


#gradient
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    opacity: 0.1;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -99999; 

}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}




  </style>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gradientscript.js"></script>
    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding : 0,
        arrows      : 'true',
        openSpeed   : '400',
        closeSpeed  : '400',
        nextClick : 'true',
        overlay : { speedOut   : 800,},
        margin      : [20, 60, 20, 60] // Increase left/right margin
        });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gradient"> 
</div>

<div id="contain">
<div class="titles"><img src="archive-icon.png" width="185" height="185" alt="studio powell michael powell studiopowell art artist books installation video" /><br /><br />M I C H A E L &nbsp; P O W E L L<br /><br /></div></div>

<div id="wrapper">
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="archive-icon.png"><img src="ruby ball.jpg" alt="" width="200" /><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery2" href="archive-icon.png"><img src="ruby ball.jpg" alt="" width="200" /><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery3" href="archive-icon.png"><img src="ruby ball.jpg" alt="" width="200" /><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery4" href="archive-icon.png"><img src="ruby ball.jpg" alt="" width="200" /></a>
<div class="hidden"><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="ruby ball.jpg"><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery2" href="ruby ball.jpg"><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery3" href="ruby ball.jpg"><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery4" href="ruby ball.jpg"></a></div></div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="wrapper2">
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery5" href="archive-icon.png"><img src="ruby ball.jpg" alt="" width="200" /><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery6" href="archive-icon.png"><img src="ruby ball.jpg" alt="" width="200" /><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery7" href="archive-icon.png"><img src="ruby ball.jpg" alt="" width="200" /><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery8" href="archive-icon.png"><img src="ruby ball.jpg" alt="" width="200" /></a>
<div class="hidden"><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery5" href="ruby ball.jpg"><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery6" href="ruby ball.jpg"><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery7" href="ruby ball.jpg"><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery8" href="ruby ball.jpg"></a></div></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the #gradient to the html tag instead of the div tag?

Comment: @dowomenfart I am not sure I understand what you mean. The div is nested within <html></html> like the rest of the site. Im very new to this so sorry,but could you explain? thanks!

Comment: Take this id="gradient" and remove it off of "<div id="gradient"></div>". Then on the html tag "<html></html>" put the id="gradient" like this "<html id="gradient"></html>"

Comment: ahh. okay, tried it, but once I did that the gradient disappeared and the whole site was given the opacity of the #gradient styling. Because of the low opacity, I think the gradient needs to remain a non-nesting div.

Comment: Can you upload it to site for I can see?

Comment: I don't see any white bar anywhere. Using Firefox 35

Comment: white bar is up siting on the bottom of the site in Firefox, Safari, Chrome

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the rule `height:100%`

Looks like for some reason or another the browser is considering the full pixel height of the window as "100%" and anything beyond that is not part of the calculation. - this is using Chrome

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer yes that seems to be the issue, but I have no clue how to fix. thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using your "gradient" div as a background but it is outside of proper nesting as @dowomenfart (what a name) pointed out.

As you noticed when you made some changes, your `opacity:0.1` rule then gives you undesired effect, but we can circumvent this issue!

First make sure your "gradient" div is the outermost nest only after `<body>`.

Remove the `height:100%` rule.
Now, remove your opacity rule, and instead apply it to your `-webkit-gradient` rule: (seeing as how you are using a library for this effect you will have to also edit your `gradientscript.js` file to support `rgba` instead of just `rgb`)

`background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, from(rgba(220, 58, 120,0.1)), to(rgba(94, 50, 213,0.1)));`

So your HTML should be like this-

```
 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
       <div id="gradient">
           <div id="container"></div>
           <div id="wrapper"></div>
           <div id="wrapper2"></div>
       </div>
    </body>
```

And your script file:

```
var r1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[0] + step * c0_1[0]);
var g1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[1] + step * c0_1[1]);
var b1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[2] + step * c0_1[2]);
var color1 = "rgba("+r1+","+g1+","+b1+",0.1)";

var r2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[0] + step * c1_1[0]);
var g2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[1] + step * c1_1[1]);
var b2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[2] + step * c1_1[2]);
var color2 = "rgba("+r2+","+g2+","+b2+",0.1)";
```

Comment: This almost worked! now the gradient flows all the way down to the end of the last fancybox, but it still does not expand to the end of the screen. zooming out or scrolling down still results in a white bar! thoughts? @RenaissanceProgrammer

Comment: Ahh sorry, I believe you should also remove `position:absolute` from the `#gradient` definition.

Comment: Sorry, I'll take another look and amend my answer when I have time in about an hour.

Comment: It worked!! I was just having a sticky footer issue on top of it. quick fix of that and prestochango!